# Problem with Classes inheritance in ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

I have Card Class, that has several properties:

- name
- value
- isPicked

[Card Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6fQ0.png)

There are also classes that inherit from it, one of them:
[Card Class inheritance Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cl0r.png)

Next, I created an array, specified the Card Class in generic, and inside I have classes there that are inherited from Card.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWaMU.png)

But when I try to access the properties of these classes, I get null, since it all refers to Card, and not to the classes that inherit from it. :(

How can i fix it?

Comment: Please do not paste images of code. Instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74172863/edit) your question with the actual code.

Comment: You're missing a call to the parent constructor from your child class. You may also want to take a look at the following Java Trail: [Inheritance (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for a general introduction to Inheritance in Java.

Comment: You have created two attributes with the same name in child and parent class. 
In the child class (Diamond Card), your constructor set child attribute not the parent attribute. 
You need to use  keyword "super"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast your object to DaimondCard. Then you will be able to access all properties of DaimondCard. You can see in below program that if we are using **((DiamondCard)card).name)** then we will be able to access properties. When you use directly call **card.name** then it will refer to Card Class.
Daimond card have Age properties which is not part of Card class so if we are using card.age it will give us error.
And to understand this behaviour refer link provided by @Janez Kuhar
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Card {
    String name;
    char value;

    Card(){}

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Card{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", value=" + value +'}';
    }
}

class DiamondCard extends Card {
    String name = "Diamond";
    char value;
    String age;

    DiamondCard(){
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "DiamondCard{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", value=" + value + '}';
    }
}
public class InheritanceDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DiamondCard diamondCard1 = new DiamondCard();
        diamondCard1.name="card1";
        diamondCard1.value='A';
        diamondCard1.age = "age";

        ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        cards.add(diamondCard1);

        cards.forEach(card -> System.out.println(card.name));
        cards.forEach(card -> System.out.println(((DiamondCard)card).name));

        cards.forEach(card -> System.out.println(card.age));
        cards.forEach(card -> System.out.println(((DiamondCard)card).age));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your child class (DiamondCard) inherit from the properties of the parent class (Card). Here is how you can fix card class:

```
    public class Card 
    {
        private String name;
        private char val;
        private boolean isPicked=false;

        public Card()
        {
           this.name="null";
           this.val=0;
           this.isPicked=false;
        }

        public Card(String name, char val, boolean isPicked)
        {
           this.setName(name);
           this.setVal(val);
           this.setIsPicked(isPicked);
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
           this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
           return this.name;
        }

        public void setVal(char val)
        {
           this.val = val;
        }

        public char getVal()
        {
           return this.val;
        }

        public void setIsPicked(boolean isPicked)
        {
           this.isPicked = isPicked;
        }

        public boolean getIsPicked()
        {
           return this.isPicked;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
           return "Card{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", value=" + val 
           +'}';
        }

        public boolean isEqual(Card other)
        {
           return (this.getName().equals(other.getName()) && 
           this.getVal()==other.getVal()
            && this.getIsPicked()==other.getIsPicked());
        }
  }
```

Here I have implement getter and setter methods to your parent class to return an instance of the variable it is set to so that you do not come across mutability problems if you say wanted to operate on a property in your class.

This is how you can fix your DiamondCard Class to reference the super in construction and inherit values.

```
    public class DiamondCard extends Card
    {
        //these are private values, so I later operate on the instance 
        //returned in the getter methods
        String name = "diamond";
        private char val; 
        private String age;

        public DiamondCard()
        {
            super();
            this.val=1;
            this.age="null";
        }

        public DiamondCard(String name, char val, boolean isPicked, String 
        age)
        {
            super(name, val, isPicked);
            this.setAge(age);
        }

        public void setAge(String age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getAge()
        {
           return this.age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Diamond Card{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", value=" + 
        val +'}';
        }

        public boolean isEqual(DiamondCard other)
        {
            return 
            (super.equals(other)&&this.getAge().equals(other.getAge()));
        }
    }
```

Here super() allows for inheritance of the properties of name, val, and isPicked. I also included default constructors in each of these classes to initialize your values without user input (say if someone declared a card class without any input for name, val, or isPicked).

Here is the front end application for the array:
public class FrontEnd
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
DiamondCard diamondCard1 = new DiamondCard("card1",'A',true,
"age");

```
             ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
             cards.add(diamondCard1);

             cards.forEach(card -> System.out.println(card.getName()));
             cards.forEach(card -> 
             System.out.println(((DiamondCard)card).getName()));

             cards.forEach(card -> System.out.println(card.getAge()));
             cards.forEach(card -> 
             System.out.println(((DiamondCard)card).getAge()));
         }
     }
```

Note that you cannot access card age, as stated by Aks 1316.